# iPhone - Best Way to Create Real Time Connectivity

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, multiplayer, multipeer-connectivity

This is a general question I was having about Multiplayer connectivity in iPhone apps. I was wondering, what is the best method for connecting two players playing a game? I know there are forms using bluetooth, peer to peer connectivity, and game center, but which is the best one for real time games. Also, are there any other forms of connection that may be better suited to do this? Lastly, I wanted to not use the game center function because I do not want to require my users to have a game center account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you asked is available in the Multipeer Connectivity documentation. It works great as long as both users are next to each other. Over the internet you will need to role your own server. A good overview is also available here: http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/